# How do I pass docker parameters such as `--cap-add=XXX` to my docker instances running in BlueData?

Tags: bluedata, bluedata-3.7

I would like to run a container with `--cap-add=IPC_LOCK`.

According to the BlueData 3.7 [release notes](http://docs.bluedata.com/37_epic-37-release-notes), IPC_LOCK is supported:

> **HAATHI-13547**: Docker configuration now includes default IPC_LOCK capability for all deployed containers.  IPC_LOCK is the feature otherwise known as memlock, required by certain customer applications. The permitted capabilities of Docker containers as expressed on the docker invocation command line when instantiating a container now includes this value explicitly.

How do I pass docker parameters such as `--cap-add=XXX` to my docker instances running in BlueData?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify `/opt/bluedata/common-install/bd_mgmt/releases/1/sys.config`. Look for `allowed_docker_caps` which already has a list of allowed capabilities.  A block of comments above that tuple list all the capabilities allowed. You can choose from them.  You have to change the file on all hosts and restart each bd_mgmt after updating the file.

Note that all new clusters created after the change will inherit these settings.