# How to add the lustre file system client to a BlueData container?

Tags: lustre, bluedata-3.7, bluedata

I'm trying to set up a lustre client ([docs](http://wiki.lustre.org/Installing_the_Lustre_Software#Lustre_Client_Software_Installation)) inside a docker container running on BlueData.

As per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56731980/how-do-i-pass-docker-parameters-such-as-cap-add-xxx-to-my-docker-instances-r), I've modified the BlueData config on each worker and the controller node:

```
$ vi /opt/bluedata/common-install/bd_mgmt/releases/1/sys.config
```

I added the SYS_ADMIN capability:

```
 {allowed_docker_caps, ["SETPCAP",
                        "SYS_ADMIN",
                        ...
```

And rebooted the host.

Next, I provisioned a Centos 7.x cluster in BlueData:

- CentOS 7.x with no pre-packaged apps or software
- Image Version: 2.2
- Distro ID: bluedata/centos7

Then I ssh'd into the Centos container:

```sh
$ ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa centos@x.x.x.x
```

Inside the container, I install the lustre client:

```
sudo yum install \
   kernel \
   kernel-devel \
   kernel-headers \
   kernel-abi-whitelists \
   kernel-tools \
   kernel-tools-libs \
   kernel-tools-libs-devel

cat >/tmp/lustre-repo.conf <<\__EOF
[lustre-server]
name=lustre-server
baseurl=https://downloads.whamcloud.com/public/lustre/latest-release/el7/server
gpgcheck=0
[lustre-client]
name=lustre-client
baseurl=https://downloads.whamcloud.com/public/lustre/latest-release/el7/client
gpgcheck=0
[e2fsprogs-wc]
name=e2fsprogs-wc
baseurl=https://downloads.whamcloud.com/public/e2fsprogs/latest/el7
gpgcheck=0
__EOF

sudo mv /tmp/lustre-repo.conf /etc/yum.repos.d/lustre.repo
sudo reboot
sudo yum install epel-release
sudo yum --nogpgcheck --enablerepo=lustre-client install lustre-client-dkms lustre-client

sudo reboot
```

However, I receive an error when I try to load the lustre module:

```
$ sudo modprobe -v lustre
```

> insmod /lib/modules/3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64/kernel/crypto/crct10dif_generic.ko.xz 
>      insmod /lib/modules/3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64/kernel/lib/crc-t10dif.ko.xz 
>      modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'lustre': Operation not permitted

I have checked the kernel version:

```
[bluedata@bluedata-2 ~]$ uname -a 
Linux bluedata-2.bdlocal 3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jun 18 16:35:19 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The lustre version I installed is 2.12:

```
kmod-lustre-client.x86_64 2.12.2-1.el7 @lustre-client 
lustre-client.x86_64 2.12.2-1.el7 @lustre-client
```

---

**Update 1**

No errors are shown with dmesg:

```
[bluedata@bluedata-3 ~]$ dmesg -c
[bluedata@bluedata-3 ~]$ sudo modprobe -v lustre
insmod /lib/modules/3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64/kernel/crypto/crct10dif_generic.ko.xz 
insmod /lib/modules/3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64/kernel/lib/crc-t10dif.ko.xz 
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'lustre': Operation not permitted
[bluedata@bluedata-3 ~]$ dmesg
```

---

**Update 2**

```
$ sudo strace modprobe lustre
```

Outputs:

```
execve("/sbin/modprobe", ["modprobe", "lustre"], [/* 16 vars */]) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x1648000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f4458ff2000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=22387, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 22387, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f4458fec000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/liblzma.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\2000\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=157424, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2249352, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f4458bac000
mprotect(0x7f4458bd1000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f4458dd0000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x24000) = 0x7f4458dd0000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libz.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\20!\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=90248, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2183272, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f4458996000
mprotect(0x7f44589ab000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f4458baa000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x14000) = 0x7f4458baa000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\220*\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=88776, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f4458feb000
mmap(NULL, 2184192, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f4458780000
mprotect(0x7f4458795000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f4458994000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x14000) = 0x7f4458994000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\240%\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=2151672, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3981792, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f44583b3000
mprotect(0x7f4458575000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f4458775000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1c2000) = 0x7f4458775000
mmap(0x7f445877b000, 16864, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f445877b000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\260l\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=141968, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2208904, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f4458197000
mprotect(0x7f44581ae000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f44583ad000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x16000) = 0x7f44583ad000
mmap(0x7f44583af000, 13448, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f44583af000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f4458fea000
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f4458fe8000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f4458fe8740) = 0
mprotect(0x7f4458775000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f44583ad000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f4458994000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f4458baa000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f4458dd0000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x621000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x7f4458ff3000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f4458fec000, 22387)           = 0
set_tid_address(0x7f4458fe8a10)         = 1264
set_robust_list(0x7f4458fe8a20, 24)     = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRTMIN, {0x7f445819d790, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7f44581a65d0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_1, {0x7f445819d820, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7f44581a65d0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x1648000
brk(0x1669000)                          = 0x1669000
brk(NULL)                               = 0x1669000
uname({sysname="Linux", nodename="bluedata-3.bdlocal", ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/modprobe.d", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=54, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/modprobe.d", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
getdents(3, /* 4 entries */, 32768)     = 128
newfstatat(3, "dccp-blacklist.conf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=215, ...}, 0) = 0
newfstatat(3, "ko2iblnd.conf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=999, ...}, 0) = 0
getdents(3, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(3)                                = 0
stat("/run/modprobe.d", 0x7ffcc1e0a640) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib/modprobe.d", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=6, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/modprobe.d", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
getdents(3, /* 2 entries */, 32768)     = 48
getdents(3, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(3)                                = 0
open("/etc/modprobe.d/dccp-blacklist.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fcntl(3, F_GETFL)                       = 0x8000 (flags O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE)
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=215, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f4458ff1000
read(3, "# DCCP is considered a potential"..., 4096) = 215
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f4458ff1000, 4096)            = 0
open("/etc/modprobe.d/ko2iblnd.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fcntl(3, F_GETFL)                       = 0x8000 (flags O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE)
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=999, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f4458ff1000
read(3, "# Currently it isn't possible to"..., 4096) = 999
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f4458ff1000, 4096)            = 0
open("/lib/modules/3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64/modules.softdep", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fcntl(3, F_GETFL)                       = 0x8000 (flags O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE)
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=518, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f4458ff1000
read(3, "# Soft dependencies extracted fr"..., 4096) = 518
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f4458ff1000, 4096)            = 0
open("/proc/cmdline", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.10.0-"..., 4095) = 193
read(3, "", 3902)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib/modules/3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64/modules.dep.bin", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=382199, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 382199, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f4458f8a000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib/modules/3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64/modules.alias.bin", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=802187, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 802187, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f4458ec6000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib/modules/3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64/modules.symbols.bin", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=537967, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 537967, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f4458e42000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib/modules/3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64/modules.builtin.bin", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=9332, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 9332, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f4458fef000
close(3)                                = 0
stat("/lib/modules/3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64/extra/lmv.ko.xz", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=58688, ...}) = 0
stat("/lib/modules/3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64/extra/mdc.ko.xz", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=81772, ...}) = 0
stat("/lib/modules/3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64/extra/fid.ko.xz", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=11592, ...}) = 0
stat("/lib/modules/3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64/extra/osc.ko.xz", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=133688, ...}) = 0
stat("/lib/modules/3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64/extra/lov.ko.xz", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=101472, ...}) = 0
stat("/lib/modules/3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64/extra/fld.ko.xz", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=14600, ...}) = 0
stat("/lib/modules/3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64/extra/ptlrpc.ko.xz", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=369448, ...}) = 0
stat("/lib/modules/3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64/extra/obdclass.ko.xz", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=270652, ...}) = 0
stat("/lib/modules/3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64/extra/lnet.ko.xz", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=174800, ...}) = 0
stat("/lib/modules/3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64/extra/libcfs.ko.xz", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=88252, ...}) = 0
stat("/lib/modules/3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64/kernel/lib/crc-t10dif.ko.xz", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2028, ...}) = 0
stat("/lib/modules/3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64/kernel/crypto/crct10dif_common.ko.xz", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2004, ...}) = 0
open("/sys/module/lustre/initstate", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/sys/module/lustre", 0x7ffcc1e0a5c0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib/modules/3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64/kernel/crypto/crct10dif_common.ko.xz", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2004, ...}) = 0
stat("/lib/modules/3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64/kernel/crypto/crct10dif_common.ko.xz", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2004, ...}) = 0
open("/sys/module/crct10dif_common/initstate", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "live\n", 31)                   = 5
read(3, "", 26)                         = 0
close(3)                                = 0
open("/sys/module/crct10dif_common/initstate", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "live\n", 31)                   = 5
read(3, "", 26)                         = 0
close(3)                                = 0
open("/sys/module/crct10dif_pclmul/initstate", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "live\n", 31)                   = 5
read(3, "", 26)                         = 0
close(3)                                = 0
open("/sys/module/crct10dif_common/initstate", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "live\n", 31)                   = 5
read(3, "", 26)                         = 0
close(3)                                = 0
open("/sys/module/crct10dif_generic/initstate", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/sys/module/crct10dif_generic", 0x7ffcc1e0a5c0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/modules/3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64/kernel/crypto/crct10dif_generic.ko.xz", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\3757zXZ\0", 6)                = 6
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_SET)                   = 0
read(3, "\3757zXZ\0\0\4\346\326\264F\2\0!\1\26\0\0\0t/\345\243\340\30l\6\267]\0?"..., 8192) = 1784
mmap(NULL, 8392704, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f4457996000
read(3, "", 8192)                       = 0
munmap(0x7f4457996000, 8392704)         = 0
init_module(0x1653f40, 6253, "")        = -1 ENOSYS (Function not implemented)
open("/sys/module/crc_t10dif/initstate", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOSYS (Function not implemented)
stat("/sys/module/crc_t10dif", 0x7ffcc1e0a5c0) = -1 ENOSYS (Function not implemented)
open("/lib/modules/3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64/kernel/lib/crc-t10dif.ko.xz", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOSYS (Function not implemented)
read(4, 0x7ffcc1e0b5f0, 6)              = -1 ENOSYS (Function not implemented)
lseek(4, 0, SEEK_SET)                   = -1 ENOSYS (Function not implemented)
read(4, 0x7ffcc1e074e0, 8192)           = -1 ENOSYS (Function not implemented)
brk(NULL)                               = -1 ENOSYS (Function not implemented)
brk(0x1e7d000)                          = -1 ENOSYS (Function not implemented)
read(4, 0x7ffcc1e074e0, 8192)           = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
close(3)                                = 0
write(2, "modprobe: ERROR: could not inser"..., 68modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'lustre': Operation not permitted
) = 68
close(4)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f4458f8a000, 382199)          = 0
munmap(0x7f4458ec6000, 802187)          = 0
munmap(0x7f4458e42000, 537967)          = 0
munmap(0x7f4458fef000, 9332)            = 0
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

---

**Update 3**

I tried installing the kmod package instead of dkms:

```
Running transaction
  Installing : kmod-lustre-client-2.12.2-1.el7.x86_64                                                                                                       1/1 
mknod: '/var/tmp/dracut.cG1SKj/initramfs/dev/null': Operation not permitted
mknod: '/var/tmp/dracut.cG1SKj/initramfs/dev/kmsg': Operation not permitted
mknod: '/var/tmp/dracut.cG1SKj/initramfs/dev/console': Operation not permitted
  Verifying  : kmod-lustre-client-2.12.2-1.el7.x86_64                                                                                                       1/1 

Installed:
  kmod-lustre-client.x86_64 0:2.12.2-1.el7                                                                                                                      

Complete!
```

I then tried again `sudo strace modprobe lustre`:

```
...
open("/lib/modules/3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64/kernel/lib/crc-t10dif.ko.xz", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOSYS (Function not implemented)
read(4, 0x7fff450be5f0, 6)              = -1 ENOSYS (Function not implemented)
lseek(4, 0, SEEK_SET)                   = -1 ENOSYS (Function not implemented)
read(4, 0x7fff450ba4e0, 8192)           = -1 ENOSYS (Function not implemented)
brk(NULL)                               = -1 ENOSYS (Function not implemented)
brk(0x1410000)                          = -1 ENOSYS (Function not implemented)
read(4, 0x7fff450ba4e0, 8192)           = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
close(3)                                = 0
write(2, "modprobe: ERROR: could not inser"..., 68modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'lustre': Operation not permitted
) = 68
close(4)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f04da388000, 383873)          = 0
munmap(0x7f04da2c4000, 802187)          = 0
munmap(0x7f04da240000, 537967)          = 0
munmap(0x7f04da3ed000, 9332)            = 0
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

---

**Update 4**

Running the container as `--privileged` has resolved the original error, but I now hit a new error:

```
[bluedata@bluedata-5 ~]$ sudo dmesg -c
[bluedata@bluedata-5 ~]$ sudo modprobe -v lustre
insmod /lib/modules/3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64/extra/ptlrpc.ko.xz 
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'lustre': Invalid argument
[bluedata@bluedata-5 ~]$ dmesg
[ 2072.258326] LNetError: 56638:0:(api-ni.c:2233:lnet_startup_lndnet()) Can't load LND tcp, module ksocklnd, rc=256
[ 2072.264113] LustreError: 56638:0:(events.c:625:ptlrpc_init_portals()) network initialisation failed
```

---

**Update 5**

The error message suggested I needed to configure the network, so I tried:

```
[bluedata@bluedata-5 ~]$ sudo modprobe lnet
[bluedata@bluedata-5 ~]$ sudo lnetctl lnet configure
```

lustre now loads without error:

```
[bluedata@bluedata-5 ~]$ sudo modprobe -v lustre
insmod /lib/modules/3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64/extra/ptlrpc.ko.xz 
insmod /lib/modules/3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64/extra/fld.ko.xz 
insmod /lib/modules/3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64/extra/lov.ko.xz 
insmod /lib/modules/3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64/extra/osc.ko.xz 
insmod /lib/modules/3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64/extra/fid.ko.xz 
insmod /lib/modules/3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64/extra/mdc.ko.xz 
insmod /lib/modules/3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64/extra/lmv.ko.xz 
insmod /lib/modules/3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64/extra/lustre.ko.xz
```

Comment: Have you checked dmesg for any errors?  Does your kernel require signed modules?

Comment: I've updated the question to show no errors in dmesg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the original steps in the question and run the container as `--privileged`.  Then loading and configuring `lnet` allowed loading the lustre module without error:

```
[bluedata@bluedata-5 ~]$ sudo modprobe lnet
[bluedata@bluedata-5 ~]$ sudo lnetctl lnet configure
[bluedata@bluedata-5 ~]$ sudo modprobe -v lustre
insmod /lib/modules/3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64/extra/ptlrpc.ko.xz 
insmod /lib/modules/3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64/extra/fld.ko.xz 
insmod /lib/modules/3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64/extra/lov.ko.xz 
insmod /lib/modules/3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64/extra/osc.ko.xz 
insmod /lib/modules/3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64/extra/fid.ko.xz 
insmod /lib/modules/3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64/extra/mdc.ko.xz 
insmod /lib/modules/3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64/extra/lmv.ko.xz 
insmod /lib/modules/3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64/extra/lustre.ko.xz 
[bluedata@bluedata-5 ~]$
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** Running with the privileged flag is not recommended.  There are other options - reach out to your local BlueData team to learn more.